# Check enum value and then add another field (Java)

Tags: java, enums, field

I have a class in Java named Course. In that class I have some private fields (ID, name, list of teachers and enum type (that can be Compulsory, Elective or Modular)). If the type of the course is Modular, there should be another field Module. How can that be done, in a different way (not to have 3 different classes CompulsoryCourse, ElectiveCourse and ModularCourse)?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can have an extra field `Module` which is optional. So it would be `null`, and its getter returns `Optional<Module>` (that way you avoid null pointer exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

This seems a case for the *Factory* or *Strategy* pattern. However that requires polymorphism.
Dynamically adding a field to a class is not possible, or better it is, but that's a bytecode manipulation topic.

You can emulate the optionality of the `Module` type field, by encapsulating it and exposing it via an `Optional<Module>` getter method, or by applying a sort of `no-op` implementation to it.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using `null` or similar...

Instead of using an enum for `type`, use a type.

```
abstract class CourseType {
    ...
}
class Modular extends CourseType {
    private Module module;
    ...
}
class Compulsory extends CourseType {
...
class Course {
    private CourseType type;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Course {
    private UUID ID;
    private String name;
    private List<String> teachers;
    private Type type;
    private String module;

    public void typeCompulsory() {
        type(Type.COMPULSORY, null);
    }

    public void typeElective() {
        type(Type.ELECTIVE, null);
    }

    public void typeModular(String module) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(module);
        type(Type.MODULAR, module);
    }

    private void type(Type type, String module) {
        this.type = type;
        this.module = module;
    }

    public enum Type {
        COMPULSORY,
        ELECTIVE,
        MODULAR
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the fact that enums are objects. Add a private field 'module' and a method 'getModule' that will return the module value for Modular course, and null for  Compulsory and Elective courses.

```
enum courseType{  
     Modular("module x"), Compulsory, Elective;
     private String module = null;
     private courseType(){}
     private courseType(String module){this.module = module;}
     public String getModule() {return this.module;}
}
```

you can also throw an exception instead:

```
enum courseType{  
    Modular("module x"), 
    Compulsory {public String getModule() { throw new AssertionError("not applicable");}}, 
    Elective {public String getModule() { throw new AssertionError("not applicable");}};

    private final String module;
    private courseType(){ this.module = null;}
    private courseType(String module){this.module = module;}
    public String getModule() { return this.module;}
    }
```